# blender python check if the Rotate or grab mode is active?

Tags: python

Is there a way to know with python if the user has activated the Rotate or grab mode ( R key or G key) for a pose bone ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect specific operator is triggered

```
import bpy

# background detection modal, self-destruct when open a new blend file, switch workspace, switch to quadviews
class XX(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.xx_modal_operator"
    bl_label = "XX Modal View3D Operator"

    INSTANCE = None
    HANDLE = None

    @classmethod
    def modal_fin(cls):
        try:
            cls.INSTANCE = None
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(cls.HANDLE, 'WINDOW')
            cls.HANDLE = None
            print("    modal finished")
        except:
            pass

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if context.area is None or context.space_data.region_quadviews:
            self.__class__.modal_fin()
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        # if event.type in {'ESC'}:
        #     self.__class__.modal_fin()
        #     return {'CANCELLED'}

        for kc in context.window_manager.keyconfigs:
            for km in kc.keymaps:
                operator = km.keymap_items.match_event(event)
                if operator and operator.active:
                    if operator.idname == "transform.translate":
                        print("When transform.translate is triggered, this message will be displayed. But when this message displayed, transform.translate is not necessarily triggered")
                        print(operator.name, operator.idname)

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        cls = self.__class__
        if cls.HANDLE is not None:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Abort, modal already running.")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            cls.INSTANCE = self
            cls.AREA = context.area

            cls.HANDLE = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "View3D not found, cannot run operator")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

def draw():
    try:
        # if open a new file, it cannot access the INSTANCE
        ins = XX.INSTANCE
    except:
        XX.modal_fin()


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(XX)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(XX)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```